# Per session payout

Tags: staking, rewards, payouts

I want a more extended than usual era period (it's pretty costly to change validators often), so it can take months on the single era. Still, it's not cool to bond validators without pay for such a long period.

So, I'm interested in a per-session payout. Is it possible to implement? I have in mind to make a new pallet with a hook that would make custom payout every here and there. (also, I will disable the staking implementation), but maybe there is a better way of achieving it.

Could you suggest any ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simplified version that demonstrates the method:

Place the payout function within the `end_session`.

https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia/blob/646ebca9e99c727febbf410007f0967610e5d39c/pallet/staking/src/lib.rs#L1029

The reward will be distributed at the end of a session.

Comment: It seems that I would need to recreate my own staking. Is it possible though, maybe somehow reuse the payout of staking?

Comment: I think that's impossible. Without the tweaking, pallet-staking's payout is binding with era.